# Using VBA to copy and paste formula

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA. I have a file which has a formula and would like to copy same on different workbooks . The file containing the formula has a fixed name whereas the other files will have different file names. After the formula is copied I will also like to move it to another folder.

I have over 300 excel files to perform this task on and I as wondering if VBA could help me on this.

please help !!
Thanking you beforehand.

Comment: @David912 Thank you for your time and patience. I am still lost my friend. Let me explain.  Suppose I have a folder with this path C:\Users\navinc\Desktop\test that contains all my excel files with file names 1 to 300.  I have a file Book1 containing the formula in range("E1:G1") which is saved in path C:\Users\navinc\Desktop\master\Book1.xlsxm. I want to copy the formula in range E1:G1 from Book1 to all the files in folder C:\Users\navinc\Desktop\test . How do you do it ? I'm sorry to bother you...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()

'DECLARE AND SET VARIABLES
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim Filename As String
Dim Path As String
Path = "C:\..." 'Enter path of XLS direcroty
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xlsm")
'--------------------------------------------
'OPEN EXCEL FILES
 Do While Len(Filename) > 0  'IF NEXT FILE EXISTS THEN
Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Path & Filename)
'
' CODE GOES HERE
'
 wbk.Close True
Filename = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: 912 Thank you for your time and patience.